# Covariance with List(of AType(of T)) where T is an interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, covariance

Have been reading up and checking other questions, but don't understand / can't seem to find my answer anywhere else.

Assume the following

```
Public Interface IAudit
Public Class FamilyAudit implements IAudit
Public Class MemberAudit implements IAudit
Public Class AuditPair(Of T As IAudit)

Dim myList as new List(of AuditPair(of IAudit))
Dim famAuditPair as new AuditPair(of FamilyAudit)
Dim memAuditPair as new AuditPair(of MemberAudit)

' This fails
myList.Add(famAuditPair)
myList.Add(memAuditPair)
```

I get compiler error that the auditPairs cannot be implicitly converted to AuditPair(of IAudit). This looks like co/contra variance.
The MSDN doc says that since 4.0 Lists should be supporting variance.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `in` / `out` variance feature applies specifically to two scenarios:

- interfaces
- delegates

It does not apply *directly* to concrete types list `List<T>`. And further, a "list" is intrinsically non-variant, since the "add" and "enumerate" would be mutually incompatible in either direction. However, a list *acting as a sequence* is covariant. Consider:

```
var list = new List<FamilyAudit>();
IEnumerable<IAudit> seq = list; // <=== covariance; the list is
                                // IEnumerable<FamilyAudit>, which
                                // can be compatible with
                                // IEnumerable<IAudit>
```

Note that this only applies to .NET 4.0 and above; on earlier versions it will refuse to compile, saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

That is because prior to 4.0, the interface is `IEnumerable<T>`, rather than the necessary `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Comment: That seems to work indeed. Checking if I now can join two lists of different IAudits and put them in

Comment: @Boris then... it can only accept values that are `AuditPair<FamilyAudit>`, or *inherited* from `AuditPair<FamilyAudit>`... which is **different** to "an `AuditPair<SomethingElse>` where `SomethingElse` : `FamilyAudit`"; that **will not** work. The variance support on lists relates to `IEnumerable<T>`. And only that.

Comment: @Mark, sorry, was editing it. Didn't know it was already visible. But your answer helps anyway. Thanks

Comment: Your answer basically tells me, it's not possible. Any suggestions to otherwise? It's an answer to my question though, so marking as such